# Angularjs is throwing Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] on node app with express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am doing a node app with express. I am trying to integrate angular into it now but I get these two errors in my chrome console.

`x GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/apx.js   localhost/:13`

`x Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=rough&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381)     angularjs:38`

here is my app.js the way static files are served:

```
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

directory structure:

`simpleapp > public > javascripts > apx.js`

`simpleapp > views > products > index.html`

products/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="rough">
 <head>
    <title></title>
 </head>

 <body ng-controller="trx">
  {{title}}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/apx.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascripts/apx.js:

```
var myapp = angular.module('rough', [])

myapp.controller('trx', function($scope){
  $scope.title = "wuewe"
});
```

Comment: can you create plunker for your issue? is your javascript getting loaded?

Comment: I don't have plunker. I am reading about it now. My js file is not getting loaded.

Comment: This issue is fixed. I had to restart my server. I had made changes earlier and did not restart server.